# Mission control shortcuts stopped working, how do I restart it?

Tags: macos, shortcut, mission-control

I have the mouse gestures such as four finger swipe up shows mission control, or four finger swipe down shows current application's windows.

Occasionally after the computer has been on for a while, the shortcuts just stop working. Is there a way I can fix it without having to restart my entire computer?

Comment: This also addresses keyboard shortcuts that stopped working or that you remapped and didn't "take it" and the accepted answer solves that too

Answer (score 8):

You can [restart Mission Control](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/23/restart-mission-control-in-os-x-lion/) using the following command in Terminal:

```
killall Dock
```

This will usually fix the mouse gesture shortcuts.